# Kendo menu is closing on click when the content is a custom layout

Tags: menu, kendo-ui

I'm having a trouble with the menu widget.

I want to have a menu item that has a custom layout as a content. Very similar to what is shown in this demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html

The "Stores" item has a custom layout, and when I click inside, the menu isn't closed, which is the behavior I want. But if I copy the code shown below to my own project, when I click inside, the menu is closed... I don't want this behavior.

Why this happen in my project and not in the demo example? How can I solve this? Maybe some javascript library in conflict?

In items that have regular items, the behavior is the same in both...

**Code (copied from the demo page):**

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
        <div id="megaStore">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    Products
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Furniture
                            <ul> <!-- moving the UL to the next line will cause an IE7 problem -->
                                <li>Tables & Chairs</li>
                                <li>Sofas</li>
                                <li>Occasional Furniture</li>
                                <li>Childerns Furniture</li>
                                <li>Beds</li>
                            </ul>


                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Decor
                            <ul> <!-- moving the UL to the next line will cause an IE7 problem -->
                                <li>Bed Linen</li>
                                <li>Throws</li>
                                <li>Curtains & Blinds</li>
                                <li>Rugs</li>
                                <li>Carpets</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Storage
                            <ul> <!-- moving the UL to the next line will cause an IE7 problem -->
                                <li>Wall Shelving</li>
                                <li>Kids Storage</li>
                                <li>Baskets</li>
                                <li>Multimedia Storage</li>
                                <li>Floor Shelving</li>
                                <li>Toilet Roll Holders</li>
                                <li>Storage Jars</li>
                                <li>Drawers</li>
                                <li>Boxes</li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Lights
                            <ul> <!-- moving the UL to the next line will cause an IE7 problem -->
                                <li>Ceiling</li>
                                <li>Table</li>
                                <li>Floor</li>
                                <li>Shades</li>
                                <li>Wall Lights</li>
                                <li>Spotlights</li>
                                <li>Push Light</li>
                                <li>String Lights</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Stores
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div id="template" style="padding: 10px;">
                                <h2>Around the Globe</h2>
                                <ol>
                                    <li>United States</li>
                                    <li>Europe</li>
                                    <li>Canada</li>
                                    <li>Australia</li>
                                </ol>
                                <img src="../../content/web/menu/map.png" alt="Stores Around the Globe" />
                                <button class="k-button">See full list</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Blog
                </li>
                <li>
                    Company
                </li>
                <li>
                    Events
                </li>
                <li disabled="disabled">
                    News
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <style scoped>
            #megaStore {
                width: 600px;
                margin: 30px auto;
                padding-top: 120px;
                background: url('../../content/web/menu/header.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
            }
            #menu h2 {
                font-size: 1em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 5px 10px;
            }
            #template img {
                margin: 5px 20px 0 0;
                float: left;
            }
            #template {
                width: 380px;
            }
            #template ol {
                float: left;
                margin: 0 0 0 30px;
                padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            }
            #template:after {
                content: ".";
                display: block;
                height: 0;
                clear: both;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            #template .k-button {
                float: left;
                clear: left;
                margin: 5px 0 5px 12px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#menu").kendoMenu();

            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: The example works fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/sb6b3/2/  What is the problem you face? Can you reproduce it in this jsFiddle?

Comment: @Antonis Thanks for your help! But I found the problem. I was using an old version of kendo (2013.1.514). When I updated to the latest (2013.2.716) the problem was gone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

I was using an old version of kendo (2013.1.514). When I updated to the latest (2013.2.716) the problem was gone.